# Does correlation based feature selection methods lead to worse performance?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, correlation

I am constrained for compute/memory and need to reduce the cardinality of my covariates. Are correlation-based methods the proper way to tackle such problem? Further, I am unable to apply PCA to my dataset as interpretability is one of the non-functional requirements of my project.

It is either correlation or picking K-best features according to Gini importance (the model in question is XGB) - which is better?

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I assume you are interested in explainable out-of-sample prediction. If you have features that are multicollinear, removing them will not hurt your performance no matter what. So if you do have some (near-)perfectly correlated features, removing one of them will be better. In any other case it is not clear a priori which will perform better once you try to predict on new data. A good way to identify robustly predictive feature would be via [cross-validation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html).